# How can I measure the time it takes to draw a window?

Tags: python, linux, performance, desktop, lag

We've all experienced the difference between a responsive system and a laggy system. Input delay. When you click it doesn't respond fast enough. When you type a character it takes too long to appear (fractions of a second).

I've written this code to measure how long it takes to draw a window but I don't think it's accurate.

How can I measure how long it takes when I press a key for that key to appear visibly on the screen?

```py
import tkinter as tk
import time

# Create a window
window = tk.Tk()

# Set the title of the window
window.title("Basic Window")

# Set the size of the window
window.geometry("300x200")

# Start the timer
start_time = time.time()

# Update the window and measure the time until it's rendered
while not window.winfo_viewable():
    window.update_idletasks()

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print("Elapsed time to render the window: {} seconds".format(elapsed_time))

# Run the window's event loop
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The problem is that there are many part you cannot measure with a software or at least very very hardly. For exemple you cannot measure the time between a key press and the CPU IO interrupt. The time between the CPU interrupt and the processes being scheduled is very hard to get (only possible in the kernel itself though there are low-level kernel profiling tools). The time between the scheduling and the event reported is quite easy to get but not in Python. The time for the GPU to show something on the screen is hard to get and its is not possible for the screen (with a software again).

Comment: Honestly, such a thing is really hard to do properly even for highly-skilled system programmer. So I advise you to take a shortcut : buy a camera and measure yourself the time between a key-press and something printed on the screen. This is very reliable with a camera having a high frame-rate (though it is not easy to detect the exact frame when the keyboard trigger the event).

Comment: There will be a way to measure interface performance somehow. Let's start there.

Comment: Note that if you want to measure the time between OS events/syscalls, then this is significantly simpler. There are several tools to do that regarding the exact events you want to measure. `strace` may help you on Linux to track interesting syscalls for example (ie. a part of what you seems to want). Note that `strace` is not very accurate for very-short timings though.

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, you can't.  These are event-driven systems.  All the commands you have in your script up until the very last one don't do any drawing at all.  With some exceptions, NO Tk calls do any drawing.  All they do is post messages to the thread's message queue.  Finally, when `window.mainloop` starts up, it begins to pop messages from that queue and dispatch them to the UI components that do the actual drawing.

The key to making a responsive UI is to make sure you get back to your message loop as quickly as possible.  As long as callbacks are quick, those messages can get dispatched, and things will be drawn.

Comment: I want to measure the linux environment the program is running in, not make a responsive UI.

Comment: There are so many, many layers here.  You have the Python Interpreter, the TCL interpreter, the Tk APIs, the gtk APIs, the X11 protocol, the X11 server, and its lower-level drivers writing to the frame buffer.  There are layers to this where you have no visibility.  Peak performance is not the usual goal here, because humans respond so much more slowly than the computer.